# Tapping on Date Picker does not popup Picker view in iOS13

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, ios13

In the app when I tap on the `UITextField` that should give me a `UIDatePicker` does not show me `UIDatePicker` on updating the iPhone to `iOS 13`. **Works fine with `iOS 12+` versions.**

I am working on latest `Xcode 11` and `macOS Mojave 10.14.6`

This is the code I am using:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let dateString: String!
    activeTextField = textField

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"

    if activeTextField == fromDateTextField && fromDateTextField.text != "" {
        dateString = fromDateTextField.text
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString!)
        datePickerView.setDate(date!, animated: false)

    } else if activeTextField == toDateTextField && activeTextField.text != "" {
        dateString = toDateTextField.text
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString!)
        datePickerView.setDate(date!, animated: false)
    }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.datePickerContainerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                                    y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 250,
                                                    width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width,
                                                    height: 250)
    }

    return false
}
```

Comment: This code is not what you should be doing to show a picker view. Simply make the picker view the `inputView` of text field. That's it. No extra code required to show the picker view.

Comment: Sorry, that didnt help. The above code (attached with the question)works fine in iOS 12 devices. Only facing the issue with iOS 13.

Comment: What do you mean it didn't help? You are doing it wrong in any version of iOS. Do it correctly and it will work in all versions of iOS.

Comment: `Simply make the picker view the inputView of text field` - Didn't seem to make any change.

On tapping text field, nothing happens.

Comment: Where did you set the text field's `inputView`? It should be done in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me :
Initialise   :  let picker = UIDatePicker()
and call createToolbar function in viewDidLoad

```
 func createToolbar() {

    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Set Date", style: .done, target: nil, action:  #selector(showDate))
    toolbar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)
    fromDateTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    fromDateTextField.inputView = picker
    toDateTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    toDateTextField.inputView = picker
    picker.datePickerMode = .date

}

 @objc func showDate() {

    let dateFormat = DateFormatter()
    dateFormat.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    let string = dateFormat.string(from: picker.date)


    if fromDateTextField.isFirstResponder {
        fromDateTextField.text = string
    }

    if toDateTextField.isFirstResponder {
        toDateTextField.text = string
    }
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Thank you @rmmaddy for the inputs :)

Answer (score -1):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var dateField: UITextField!
var datePicker :UIDatePicker!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    datePicker = UIDatePicker.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.size.width, height: 200))
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.dateChanged), for: .allEvents)
    dateField.inputView = datePicker
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.datePickerDone))
    let toolBar = UIToolbar.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.size.width, height: 44))
    toolBar.setItems([UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil), doneButton], animated: true)
    dateField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
}

@objc func datePickerDone() {
    dateField.resignFirstResponder()
}

@objc func dateChanged() {
    dateField.text = "\(datePicker.date)"
}
}
```

try this

Comment: Please do not post code-only answers. A good answer explains what was wrong and it explains how the answer fixes the issue.